# Is it possible to check permissions on a Spring Controller method without executing it?

Tags: java, spring, security, rest, spring-security

The JS client of my REST API wants to know, is a query to a certain URL permitted or not. Permissions are configured on the controller methods using the standard annotations:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/books")
public class BooksController {

  @RequestMapping("read")
  @Secured("ROLE_READER")
  public ModelAndView read(int id) { ... }

  @RequestMapping("write")
  @Secured("ROLE_WRITER")
  public ModelAndView write(int id, String contents) { ... }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/util")
public class UtilController {

  @RequestMapping("check")
  public String check(String url) {
    //if url is "/books/read" and isUserInRole("ROLE_READER")
    //or url is "/books/write" and isUserInRole("ROLE_WRITER")
    //return "true", otherwise "false"
  }
}
```

For read-only methods it would be possible to program the JS client to try and access a URL itself, ignore the result and look only on the status (200 or 403-Forbidden). It's not best performance-wise, but at least correct functionally. But for the write method I see no way to work around. Hope there is a sane solution for this problem.

P.S. Thanks to @Bogdan for the solution. This is the full text of the method I need:

```
@Autowired
WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator evaluator;

@RequestMapping("/check")
public String check(String url, Authentication authentication) {
    return Boolean.toString(evaluator.isAllowed(url, authentication));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the `UtilController` you posted you could go with something like a [WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.html), maybe also have a look at how the [authorize tag](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#the-authorize-tag) works.

Additionally, depending on what you are doing, something like this could also work:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/books")
public class BooksController {

  @RequestMapping("read")
  @Secured("ROLE_READER")
  public ModelAndView read(int id) { ... }

  @RequestMapping("canRead")
  @Secured("ROLE_READER")
  public void canRead() { }

  @RequestMapping("write")
  @Secured("ROLE_WRITER")
  public ModelAndView write(int id, String contents) { ... }

  @RequestMapping("canWrite")
  @Secured("ROLE_WRITER")
  public void canWrite() { }
}
```

You can also check for multiple roles with:

```
@RequestMapping("canReadOrWrite")
@Secured({"ROLE_READER", "ROLE_WRITER"})
public void canReadOrWrite() { }
```

You can then check the status code for calling the new methods.

Comment: @Andrew Skiba: I've added some details to my answer, a simpler approach in case those are your only places where you need to perform the check

Comment: Thanks, WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator is exactly what I looked for. I edited the OP to include the solution.

Comment: Hi Bodjan. We are trying to use the solution using WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator but our evaluator always returns true. Even with a DenyAll annotation. We think @autowired is not working fine and we are getting always a simple WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator that ignores our spring-security configuration. Any idea on how to get a proper WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator? Maybe through SecurityContextHolder?