# Is it possible to know if a url is accesible when using Spring MVC and Spring Security @PreAuthorize annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, url, spring-security

In our web project we're using Spring security 3.2.3.RELEASE and Spring MVC (and other Spring stuff) 4.0.5.RELEASE.

We have our controller method annotated like this:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_MANAGER')")
  public String register() {
```

My question is if there is a way i can ask spring security if my user can call to

```
http://localhost:8080/project/register
```

The main objective is to develop a metod to call before rendering a url so if user cannot reach this url, the system does not render it.

I've developed a similar aproach with JSF and Spring Security using something like this:

```
@Autowired
private WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator webInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator;

public boolean allowedForAction(String action) {
  log.debug("Checking action/url:" + action);
  Authentication a = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
  NavigationCase nc = ((ReloadAfterNavigationFix) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication()
    .getNavigationHandler()).getNavigationCase(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), null, action);
  if (nc != null) {
    return webInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.isAllowed(nc.getToViewId(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()), a);
  }
  return false;
}
```

But i'm not sure that webInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator works for annotated methods in controllers like te one in the example. I think it willonly work with configured url patterns in spring-security.xml

Any idea?

Comment: I've tried to use solutions like the one provided in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213825/is-it-possible-to-check-permissions-on-a-spring-controller-method-without-execut/27213914#27213914, "solution") but i'm not able to get a WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator that contains annotation based permissions. They only checks security agains url patterns defined in spring-security.xml